# error on sending mail while mail is sent succesfully

Tags: php, email

I have a function for sending mail. When i use it, mail is sent succesfully but the page ends up in an error 500.

On top of the php file i have:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

The function looks like this:

```
    function sendmail($to, $subject, $message)
{
    $headers = "From: info@mosaique-oost.nl\r\n";
    $headers.="Reply-to: info@mosaique-oost.nl \r\n";
    $headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.="Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    // echo "To: ".$to;
    // echo "Subject: ".$subject;
    // echo "Message: ".$message;
    //die("Headers: ".$headers);
    try{
        mail(mysql_escape_string($to), mysql_escape_string($subject), mysql_escape_string($message), mysql_escape_string($headers));
    }catch (Exception $e)
    {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
    die($headers);
}
```

I don't receive any detailed error information, just the error 500.
As i think, with this code i should come in a die() statement when the mail is sent succesfully

In the log of the mail server, there is no error reported to the send-request.

php -l says there are no syntac errors in the php files
Any suggestion (highly appreciated)?

Thanks, Edwin

Comment: Error 500 == look into the error.log / And no, the mail/mime headers do not typically belong in a die() message. / Furthermore, mysql escaping has no place in mail() parameters. (Do not apply arbitrarily, read up on which context requires which escaping.)

Comment: Where to find the error log on windows ?
the die message is to give me information on why i got the error.
escaping may be useless but it wouldn;'t hurt right ?

Comment: Depends on your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

can you use this mail / php?

```
$to      =  "email@touser.com";
$subject = "something here";
$headers = "From: example@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo "Susscess";
}else{
    echo "Not Susscess";
}
```

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it.

for

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to be effective
the path to the error log file in php.ini must also be set.

```
; Log errors to specified file.
error_log = c:\php\error.log
```

With this set i found out that the default timezone wasn't set.